# Spreadsheet formula taking too long to run - script advise

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following formula is taking far to long to run.

```
= TRANSPOSE (
    IFERROR (
      INDEX (
        FILTER(Students!B:B;
         REGEXMATCH(Students!B:B; C50), 
         REGEXMATCH(Students!B:B; B50),  
         REGEXMATCH(Students!C:C; F50)
       ));"NO MATCH"
  ))
```

Any suggestions on the coding would be great, as I know very little programming.

Thanks
T

Comment: That is not apps script. Its spreadsheet formulas. Put the correct tags.

Comment: I am trying to understand how to convert a spreadsheet formula into a custom google script.

Comment: Provide more explanation on what it does. A script wil be slower than a formula if you code it using the same algorithm. You might need to change strategies.

Comment: It checks the first name in C50, surname in B50, and employer in F50 for a match against names listed in Sheet "Students".  If a match lists and if not = no match.

Comment: You're still not explaining how many rows you have etc. You wont be able to make it faster by just writting a script that does the same. Investigate why its slow now.

Comment: About a thousand rows and will keep adding. Its slow because it is using regexmatch will rerun each time there is a spreadsheet change.  I would like help to make a custom script which will trigger as and when required.

Comment: Dont know how complex is your regex. Fast code might mean you need to store the data in scriptdb and then find the items with a query. Scriptdb will only match exact strings so you will need to store it in a special way to be able to find it on scriptdb. Gets complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a custom function that can replace the formula you're using. For example:

```
=listStudents(C50,B50,F50)
```

If used that way, you'll still have constant recalculation, but it should be much faster than the regex tests. Alternatively, the same function could be invoked from a menu item, and used to populate a given target range in the sheet, thereby avoiding automatic recalculation altogether.

Code:

```
/**
 * Custom spreadsheet function to produce a list of names of
 * students that match the given criteria.
 */
function listStudents( givenName, surname, employer ) {
  var matches = [];  // matching students will be placed in this array
  var HEADERS = 1;   // # rows of header info at top of sheet
  var FULLNAME = 1;  // Column containing full names (B)
  var EMPLOYER = 2;  //                   employers (C)

  // Array filter function - returns true if conditions match
  function test4match( row ) {
    return ( row[FULLNAME].indexOf(givenName) !== -1 &&
             row[FULLNAME].indexOf(surname) !== -1 &&
             row[EMPLOYER].indexOf(employer) !== -1)
  }

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Students');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues().slice(HEADERS);  // All data from sheet, without headers

  var filteredData = data.filter(test4match);   // Get matching rows
  for (var i=0; i<filteredData.length; i++) {
    matches.push(filteredData[i][FULLNAME]);    // Then produce list of names
  }

  return [matches];  // Return a 2-d array, one row
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me work with that.  Adding a menu item is a really good idea.